# How to empty date (or what should I add to do it) from a layout button datepicker?

Tags: java, android, layout, datepicker

My question is relatively simple.
I have a layout with a datepicker button which works perfectly, but, I need this field can stay empty.
And, when the user select a date from this button, it's impossible afterwards to empty the field.
Should I add another button to do the trick or is there another way with an option of this button itself ?

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/stockAddInputExpDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebutton"
        android:hint="@string/dateFormat"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:padding="8dp" />

public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";
final Button stockExp = mPromptsView.findViewById(R.id.stockAddInputExpDate);
final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(Consts.DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
final DatePickerDialog expiryDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, (view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    stockExp.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
    view.updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
}, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
stockExp.setOnClickListener(v -> expiryDatePicker.show());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without answer, the only solution I found was to add another button:

```
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/stockExpDateReset"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:padding="8dp" />
```

then:

```
final Button stockExp = mPromptsView.findViewById(R.id.stockAddInputExpDate);
final Button stockExpReset = mPromptsView.findViewById(R.id.stockExpDateReset);
stockExpReset.setOnClickListener(v -> stockExp.setText(""));
```